# Mensaje de alerta en css

Tags: html5, css

Estoy usando los mensajes de error de html

```
<form>
  <input required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

mi pregunta es: se puede modificar el letrero? hacerlo mas grande, cambiar el color y demas... lo muestro en una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con mensajes de error de html?

Comment: @AntoTGa disculpa, modifique mi pregunta

Comment: Ese cuadro de texto que se muestra es generado por el navegador, en este caso es Chrome, para poder mostrar o modificar algo así tendrías que hacerlo con un poco de código extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes existía la forma de hacerlo en chrome con los pseudo-elementos, pero dejaron de funcionar en 2013.

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050

La única manera de implementar tu estilo personalizado es que hagas un sistema de validación desde cero.

Answer (score 3):

**No es posible** cambiar  estilos del mensaje de errores de validación  ya que estos son propios del navegador. Antes se podía realizar en `chrome` [form_validation_messages](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#form_validation_messages) haciendo uso de `pseudo-elementos`

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper
::-webkit-validation-bubble-heading
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
::-webkit-validation-bubble-text-block
```

Pero a partir de la `versión 28` Chrome eliminó el Soporte para estos `pseudo-elementos .`

Lo que se puede es cambiar el mensaje que se presenta:

```
<input required  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('nuevo mensaje a mostrar')"/>
```